# How can I use TOP and conditionally ignore a UNION ALL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, optimization

I'm querying a table which contains a full-text index for the top results of the user's search, and then I'm appending the results of a wildcard search to the end of that.

Here's my slightly simplified SQL...

```
SELECT TOP(@top) * FROM     
(       
    SELECT TOP (@top) ft.[RANK], p.ProductID, p.Name FROM dbo.Product p 
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Product, *, @search_term) AS ft ON p.ProductID = ft.[KEY]
    ORDER BY ft.[RANK] * p.Popularity DESC

    UNION ALL

    SELECT TOP (@top) 0 AS [RANK], p.ProductID, p.Name FROM dbo.Product p 
    WHERE (NOT p.ProductID IN (SELECT [KEY] FROM FREETEXTTABLE(dbo.Product, *, @search_term)))
    AND   (p.Name LIKE '%' + @search_term + '%')
    ORDER BY p.Popularity DESC
) AS results
```

This all works and has been live for some time.

Now here's the tricky part.  I recently discovered that this is one of the more expensive queries on the website.  And I looked at the query plan and found that the LIKE '%%' part of the query is incurring a 50-80% cost.  This isn't a big surprise really, as wildcard searches tend to be slow.  The trouble is that the second half of the UNION ALL doesn't need to run when the first half has returned enough rows by itself.

Is there a way to **not** perform the UNION ALL when the first half (the full-text search) returns all the rows I need?

Comment: Could store result set into temp table, if @@ROWCOUNT < @top, UNION ALL with LIKE %% query, else return temp table. That said, I have not tested to ensure that that activity is any more efficient, which is why this is a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
SELECT TOP (@top) ..., ft.[RANK] * p.Popularity INTO #foo ... <FT query>;

IF @@ROWCOUNT < @top
  INSERT #foo SELECT TOP (@top) ..., p.Popularity FROM <like query>;

SELECT TOP (@top) ... FROM #foo ORDER BY Popularity DESC;
```

It's a little more I/O, but may be worth the offset.

You may also consider just returning the first query to the client, and returning a *second* resultset only in that case where the first one wasn't enough, and make the application smart enough to merge the resultsets. This will only work if the intention is to show ft.[RANK] * p.Popularity *before* any of the results ranked just by p.Popularity alone.

Comment: Well, guess my comment was on the right track then, heh. Nice to see an answer that agrees with what my limited SQL experience guessed.

Comment: Thanks man.  This is sort of what I suspected.  I tried it out with my sample of searches, and the number of reads is about 10% higher with this approach.  The CPU usage is roughly the same, and the duration is about the same as well.  So it appears that my original query is what I should stick with for now.  Still, I'll accept this answer as it was definitely helpful.

Comment: My last paragraph may warrant some testing as well. It will definitely consume less resources in the case where the first query satisfies @top, but it requires some changes to application logic.

Comment: True, I might try it out.  Although, I've just looked across a larger time window and found that there are 4 queries that are more expensive than this one.  So I should focus on those first.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way that you could do it in a single statement, but you could check `@@rowcount` after the the first query and only fire the second if it is not high enough